# how to set up Google Search Applience and connect it to WordPress

Tags: wordpress, configuration, proxy, google-search-appliance

My company just set up a new service. We are going to use WordPress as our CMS. To solve the WordPress search engine issue we got the Google Search Appliance. Unfortunately after setting us the GSA the collections does not give us any results.
Does anyone have an experience with GSA and WP?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to add an example source code to your post? You can doing that by using the edit link underneath your post.

Comment: Are you just doing a Web crawl without any authentication? What csn you see in Index Diagnostics on the GSA admin console? Csn you share your collection definitions?

Comment: Can you check the GSA admin console to see if there are any crawling errors? Also, is your WordPress hosted internally or on the public website. Check network connectivity to your WordPress from the GSA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be an exact answer to your question, but you may want to look at other solutions for your Wordpress site that are not GSA. For example, Algolia has a search plugin that takes just 2 minutes to install and set up, with out-of-the-box relevance, typo-tolerance & a great analytics dashboard to monitor activity.

If there isn't a particular reason you've opted for GSA (curious to know if there is), this might be an easier solution than building out (or buying) a connect.